# How to delete brackets from array, but keep quotes

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have an array, with even number of elements:

```
var peoples = [
        ["1", "Adam", "Jones"],
        ["2", "Michael", "Jordan"],
        ["3", "Frank", "Forman"],
        ["4", "John", "Bryant"],
        ["5", "James", "Johnson"],
        ["6", "Vincent", "Carter"],
        ["7", "George", "Williams"],
        ["8", "Brandon", "Clarkson"]
];
```

and I’m trying to merge arrays in pairs by following pattern:

```
["1", "Adam", "Jones", "2", "Michael", "Jordan"]
["3", "Frank", "Forman","4", "John", "Bryant"]
```

etc.

I have a problem with following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < peoples.length / 2; i++) {
        array1[i].push(array2[i].join(","))
    }
```

which is generating that result:

```
["1","Adam","Jones","2,Michael,Jordan"]
```

and it should be:

```
["1","Adam","Jones","2","Michael","Jordan"]
```

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/danny3b/k5hza694/

Comment: you are using `Array.prototype.join` that joins `2, Micheal, Jordan`... you don't need for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've already done it by myself. I was looking for concat() method.

```
for (var i = 0; i < peoples.length / 2; i++) {
        array1[i] = array1[i].concat(array2[i])
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danny3b/rfju9949/

Comment: Yes, now you add array elements, with join you created one string and added it to the array as one element.

Answer (score 0):

What join does is concatenating all of the strings in the array. Instead of that, you should insert all of the elements in there.